# Iterate through lines in jekyll markdon

Tags: css, formatting, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I have fetched a passage from a CSV data file in **Jekyll** via a markdown loop.

Now that I would like to display the lines as individual headings.
Is there a way around

```
data = "this is the first line
this is the second line"
```

The above data variable when brought under markdown via code

```
#### {{data}}
```

What results is that the first line is brought under h4 and the second line is left out

```
<h4>this is the first line <br /></h4>
<p>this is the second line</p>
```

I would require the following though

```
<h4>this is the first line <br></h4>
<h4>this is the second line</h4>
```

**Question**
Is there a workaround that brings individually split lines into *distinct h4 tags*.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<h4>{{ data | newlines_to_br }}</h4>
```

It would result into:

```
<h4>this is the first line<br>this is the second line</h4>
```

Comment: `<h4>{{ data | newlines_to_br }}</h4>` **works** well

`#### {{ data | newlines_to_br }}` **does'nt** work

_Why so ?_

Comment: What are the #### for?

Comment: #### mardown [https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#headers]

Comment: HTML in markdown is valid... however, liquid should be used in the layout, not in the markdown.

Comment: Remember again i am grateful for your answer here, but i am too low on points to upvote !!
But from the webpage (https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/orderofinterpretation/)
liquid is processed before moving into md -> html conversion
I am puzzled though.

Comment: Or perhaps in `#### {{ data | newline_to_br }}`  
first line is applied a h4 whereas later lines skip the h4
and in `<h4> {{ data | newline_to_br }} </h4>`
does the job by bringing entire content between h4 tags